# Symbol to denote "weak star convergence"

Tags: stacking-symbols

how do I type the weak star convergence symbol, i.e. star symbol over `\rightharpoonup`?

I tried `\xrightharpoon{\ast}`, but it is not working.

Answer (score 7):

The use of `\overset` (`amsmath` package) is the canonical answer to your question.  However, if the vertical spacing needs a different value, one can use the `stackengine` package to achieve it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\begin{document}
$a \overset{\ast}{\rightharpoonup} b$

$a \mathrel{\ensurestackMath{\stackon[1pt]{\rightharpoonup}{\scriptstyle\ast}}} b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The LaTeX kernel provides the macro `\stackrel`. PlainTeX provides the instruction `\buildrel`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$a\stackrel{\ast}{\rightharpoonup}b$

$a\buildrel\ast\over\rightharpoonup b$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Brings new meaning to the expression, "the stars are aligned..."

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes -- :-) It *is* sort of remarkable that there are (at least!) four different methods available:  your StackEngine-based method, `\overset` (from the `amsmath` package), `\stackrel` (from the LaTeX kernel), *and* `\buildrel` (a PlainTeX macro that's also featured in the LaTeX kernel.)

Comment: Well, you know what my profile says... "As a hobby, I enjoy fonts... and reinventing the wheel."

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - Incidentally, *if* the objective were (in part...) to truly reinvent the wheel, i.e., to replicate exactly the look produced by `\buildrel`, `\stackrel`, and `\overset` using the StackEngine machinery, I might be tempted to replace `[1pt]` with `[2pt]` or, better still, `[0.45ex]`.

Comment: Indeed...pretending that I'm not *actually* reinventing the wheel is one of the secrets to my success.  Shhh.